# Appended input field elements are not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am creating form in angularjs. In that, I am creating add more fields functionality by clicking on "Add more" button. I've implemented add more functionality using javascript.
Below is the  code for HTML:

```
<form method="POST" name="form" ng-submit="insert(user)" role="form">                              
    <div class="top_gets" id="innerdivs">                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        <input ng-model="user.amount"  type="text"/>                                                                                                                                            
        <input ng-model="user.description" type="text"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        <input type="submit" onclick="addMore();" value="Add more"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save & Continue" class="save_gets" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    </div>  
</form>
```

Below is Javascript Code:

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function addMore() {
        counter += 1;
        var div = document.getElementById('innerdivs');
        var innerdiv = '<div id="innerdivs"><!-- Same Form Field Elements---></div>';
        $('#innerdivs').append(innerdiv);
    }
</script>
```

My problem is, whenever I add more fields by clicking on "Add more" button and submit the form, then only first loaded input fields posts/sends the data means newly appended field input does not posts the data. Whatever the fields are appended using javascritpt that won't works that is form does not sends/posts the inputs. This works with core PHP but it does not works in angularjs. Is there any way to fix this in angularjs?

Comment: Are you adding name attributes to the created inputs? Also, your div variable is unnecessary if you are using a jQuery selector.

Comment: ya I am adding name. And I also adding ng-model with increment counter in javascirpt

Comment: Can you recreate in a simple jsfiddle?

Comment: As a guess, I'd say it's because your template is not compiled once you're adding elements outside the angular context. Try having a div with an ng-repeat, and have the button push an object to an array that angular is already watching, and bind to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it absolutely wrong. You shall not add dom elements manually. Instead, you shall have array in controller and push new object in it:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="save(users)" role="form" ng-controller="addUserCtrl">
    <div class="top_gets" ng-repeat="user in users">
        <input ng-model="user.amount" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="user.description" type="text"/>
        <input type="button" ng-click="addMore();" value="Add more" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save & Continue" class="save_gets" />
    </div>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
angular.module(<module_name>).controller('addUserCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.users = [{}];
    scope.addMore = function () {
        scope.users.push({});
    };
    scope.save = function () {
        // send `scope.users` to server with $http or $resource
    };
}]);
```